# Component content not imported when importing styled components

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I am building a site using React  and have decided to use Styled Components. I have a component that is styled with Styled Components and is receiving a prop from my homepage where I am using an instance of this component. I have the styling being pulled into the homepage, but it is not pulling in the content of the component. When if I just pull in the whole component it pulls in the content fine, but it doesn't allow me to pass the prop, but if I import the component styling it doesn't pull in the content of the component, but the prop passes properly. So I need some help with how to pull in the content and styling and get the prop to pass.

I am pretty new to Gatsby and Styled Components so thanks for any help.

**My Component Code**

```
import React from 'react'
import styled from "styled-components"
import { useStaticQuery, graphql } from 'gatsby'

export const WhyChooseSection = styled.section`
  border-bottom: 1px solid var(--charcoal);
`

export const WhyChooseH2 = styled.h2`
  display: ${(props) => props.displayH2};
  text-align: center;
`

export const WhyChooseContent = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1160px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-top: 40px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
  column-gap: 100px;
  row-gap: 30px;

  @media(min-width: 992px) {
    justify-content: space-between;
    column-gap: 0;
  }

  .why-icon {
    width: 180px;
    height: 145px;
    text-align: center;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    gap: 20px;

    p {
      margin-bottom: 0;
      font-size: 19px;
      font-weight: var(--font-bold);
    }
  }
`

export function WhyChooseIcons() {
  const data = useStaticQuery(graphql`
    {
      whyChooseIcons: allWp {
        nodes {
          acfOptionsOfficeSettings {
            whyChooseInteriorDetails {
              whyChooseIcons {
                whyChooseIconGraphic {
                  altText
                  id
                  sourceUrl
                }
                whyChooseIconTitle
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  `)

  return (
    <>
    {data.whyChooseIcons.nodes.map((node, index) => (
      <WhyChooseSection key={index}>
        <WhyChooseH2>Why Choose Interior Details?</WhyChooseH2>
        <WhyChooseContent>
          {node.acfOptionsOfficeSettings.whyChooseInteriorDetails.whyChooseIcons && node.acfOptionsOfficeSettings.whyChooseInteriorDetails.whyChooseIcons.map((item) => (
            <div className='why-icon' key={item.whyChooseIconGraphic.id}>
              <img src={item.whyChooseIconGraphic.sourceUrl} alt={item.whyChooseIconGraphic.altText} />
              <p>{item.whyChooseIconTitle}</p>
            </div>
          ))}
        </WhyChooseContent>
      </WhyChooseSection>
    ))}
    </>
  )
}

export default WhyChooseIcons
```

**My Homepage Code**

```
import * as React from "react"
// import styled from "styled-components"
import { graphql } from 'gatsby'

import Seo from "../components/seo"
import Hero from '../components/heroComponent'
import { WhyChooseSection } from '../components/whyChooseIcons'
import { WhyChooseH2 } from '../components/whyChooseIcons'
import { WhyChooseContent } from '../components/whyChooseIcons'
import HomeProducts from '../components/homeProducts'
import HomeTestimonials from '../components/testimonials'
import HomeNewHomes from '../components/homeNewHomes'
import HomeFamilyTreatment from '../components/homeFamilyTreatment'
import HomeSolutions from '../components/homeSolutions'
import HomeMotorization from '../components/motorizationComps'
import HomeBrands from '../components/homeBrands'
import CTAOne from '../components/ctaOne'

const IndexPage = (hero) => {
  const heroData = hero.data.homeHero

  return (
    <>
      {heroData.edges.map(({ node }, index) => (
        <Hero key={index} heroTitle={node.template.homePage.heroH1} heroSubTitle={node.template.homePage.heroParagraph} heroBg={node.template.homePage.heroBackground.gatsbyImage} heroBtnOneText={node.template.homePage.heroButton1Text} heroBtnOneURL={node.template.homePage.heroButton1Url} heroBtnTwoText={node.template.homePage.heroButton2Text} heroBtnTwoURL={node.template.homePage.heroButton2Url} />
      ))}
      <WhyChooseSection>
        <WhyChooseH2 displayH2="none"></WhyChooseH2>
        <WhyChooseContent></WhyChooseContent>
      </WhyChooseSection>
      <HomeProducts />
      <HomeTestimonials />
      <HomeNewHomes />
      <HomeFamilyTreatment />
      <HomeSolutions />
      <HomeMotorization />
      <HomeBrands />
      <CTAOne />
    </>
  )
}

export default IndexPage

export const Head = () => <Seo title="Home" />

export const HeroContent = graphql`
  {
    homeHero: allWpPage(filter: {template: {templateName: {eq: "Home Template"}}}) {
      edges {
        node {
          template {
            ... on WpHomeTemplate {
              homePage {
                heroH1
                heroParagraph
                heroButton1Text
                heroButton1Url
                heroButton2Text
                heroButton2Url
                heroBackground {
                  gatsbyImage(placeholder: BLURRED, width: 1920)
                  altText
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
`
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not pulling content"? If you mean that your `<WhyChooseSection>` component is not rendering the children nodes passed into it from the homepage, that's because you're missing the `children` prop.

Comment: Thanks for looking at my question. That may be the case, it is pulling in the html, but not the dynamic content that is being pulled into the component. How would I add the "children" prop?

Comment: @Terry - Can you please help me learn where to put the children prop you were mentioning? Is there anything else I can provide to make this easier for you to answer?

Comment: Shouldn't you just be using `<WhyChooseIcons />` on your index page? The component will handle its own internal rendering.

Comment: That would be ideal because it does render the content properly, but the prop "displayH2" that I am trying to pass to the component to hide the H2 doesn't seem to pass properly. If I add `<WhyChooseIcons displayH2="block" />` it doesn't seem to send that info to the styled component function. I must be missing something.

Comment: Why would it? The `WhyChooseIcons` is handling its own internal content and is not using the child nodes passed to it at all. Who should have the responsibility? The index page, or the `WhyChooseIcons` component? If you remove all the child nodes on the index page you will realise that the component still renders just fine.

Comment: Maybe I didn't explain my goal here. In my component I have a H2 tag that I need to hide on the homepage, but not on the other pages I am pulling the component into. So I was trying to pass a prop `displayH2="none"` from the homepage to tell the styled component function `${(props) => props.displayH2};` to display "none" so it would hide on the homepage, but not the other locations. Everything is rendering fine now, but I can't get it to pass that prop to the component now. Thanks for your patience since I am new to styled components.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you only want to pass a prop into your `<WhyChooseIcons>` component and that the component itself renders its own content, there is no need to provide any children node to it in the consuming parent.

Simply update your `<WhyChooseIcons>` component to accept a prop that it will pass to its inner child. Let's name it `displayH2` and we can simply pass it into the `<WhyChooseH2>` component by doing this: `<WhyChooseH2 displayH2={displayH2}>`. So your component definition now looks like this:

```
export function WhyChooseIcons({ displayH2 }) {
  // Rest of the component logic here

  return (
    <>
    {data.whyChooseIcons.nodes.map((node, index) => (
      <WhyChooseSection key={index}>
        <WhyChooseH2 displayH2={displayH2}>Why Choose Interior Details?</WhyChooseH2>
        {/* Other content here */}
      </WhyChooseSection>
    ))}
    </>
  )l
};
```

Then in the file where you consume this component, it is just a matter of passing `"none"` to the prop:

```
<WhyChooseSection displayH2="none">
```

**HOWEVER** this feel like a XY problem to me, because all you want is to control the conditional rendering of this component. What you can do is to create a prop on your component that determines whether `<WhyChosseH2>` should be rendered or not.

```
export const WhyChooseH2 = styled.h2`
  text-align: center;
`

export function WhyChooseIcons({ shouldHideH2 }) {

  return (
    <>
    {data.whyChooseIcons.nodes.map((node, index) => (
      <WhyChooseSection key={index}>
        {!shouldHideH2 && <WhyChooseH2>Why Choose Interior Details?</WhyChooseH2>}
        {/* Other content here */}
      </WhyChooseSection>
    ))}
    </>
  )
}
```

Then you can just control H2 rendering with a true/false boolean:

```
{/* To show it, just don't set the prop */}
<WhyChooseIcons />

{/* To hide it, both ways are valid */}
<WhyChooseIcons shouldHideH2 />
<WhyChooseIcons shouldHideH2={true} />
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I was able to get it to work now and learned something new.